# AWS root account cannot access organizational accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I am writing an application for AWS platform, which was planned to be launched from the root account, with root credentials. At this point I need to stop some of the machines started by the AWS organizations member accounts.

By default AWS organizations doesn't give access to root account to look or manage resources to other member's account. So I tried using temporary credentials and tried to assume a role created by the target account.

More on that here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

On the other hand it doesn't allow root account to assume roles, and throws such exception.

```
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 7bee7537-48e0-11e9-bb1a-bb36134736e4)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1695) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1350) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1101) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:758) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:732) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:714) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:674) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:656) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:520) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.475.jar:na]
at...
```

Is there any way get around this problem? For example, somehow to give the root access to everything or let it assume roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please don't use your Root account!  Best practice is to remove access keys from the root account, add an MFA token and lock it away.  We have a large AWS Organization structure and we don't use the root accounts for anything other than where it's [absolutely required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tasks-that-require-root.html).

See the [IAM Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) user guide, specifically the section: [Lock Away Your AWS Account Root User Access Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials)

### For your described administrative purposes, use IAM Users

IAM Users can assume Roles.  Recommended steps:

1. Create IAM Group and attach the required policy for admin permissions. The `AdministratorAccess` policy is an easy pre-built policy that gives full admin access within the current account, but to assume roles into sub-accounts, all you really need to allow is the `sts:AssumeRole` action.

   - [Creating Your First IAM Admin User and Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html)
   - [Granting a User Permissions to Switch Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html)
2. Create an IAM User and assign it to the IAM Group.

   - [Adding and Removing Users in an IAM Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups_manage_add-remove-users.html)
3. Create the target Role in your sub-accounts with a Policy to allow actions in that sub-account and with a Trust Relationship defined for your IAM user in the master Org account.

   - [Creating a Role to Delegate Permissions to an IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html)
   - NOTE: Sounds like you may already have this, but check the trust relationship to make sure.
4. Authenticate your app via IAM user credentials, temp credentials, etc.

   - NOTE: The temp credentials doc that you linked is for IAM Users, I'd recommend trying it again once you have a proper IAM user setup.
   - There are many ways to authenticate to AWS services, as another example see: [Assuming an IAM Role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

Additional: Not sure what you're building, but if appropriate, [Consider Using Service-linked Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html) to directly provide the app the specific permissions it needs--rather than dealing with user credentials.